# CGI Perl - changing action and mode variables

Tags: perl, variables, cgi, action, mode

I am somewhat of a novice with CGI Perl and am working on a web app that uses 'mode' and 'action' variables to determine which pages load.

```
$mode   = param('mode');
$action = param('action');

  if ($mode eq 'page1') {

      if ($action 'eq') {

          &performAction;
      }
      displayPage1;
  }
  elsif ($mode eq 'page2') {

      &displayPage2
  }
```

During development I have been having trouble figuring out the best way to set these variables when trying to navigate to different modes/actions after a form submit.

In some cases, putting a hidden value in the form will work

```
hidden(-name=>'action',-value=>'save')
```

but sometimes it will not. In case of the latter,  putting param('action',"save") before the form will make the action change when the form is submitted.
**I am unable to figure out why this happens though, are there factors that affect these two variables that I am unaware of?**

What I now need to do is have two buttons on the same form, one which will just set the action to save the form data, and another which will save the form data but navigate to another mode/page with that form data.

**If anyone could at least point me in the right direction for what I should be researching I would be greatly appreciative.**

Comment: How about passing params in query string on button click. See if it helps or if you haven't tried this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the CGI module implements a state-preserving behavior called "sticky" fields. The way this works is that if you are regenerating a form, the methods that generate the form field values will interrogate param() to see if similarly-named parameters are present in the query string. If they find a like-named parameter, they will use it to set their default values.

You want

```
hidden(-name=>'action', -value=>$new_value, -override=>1)
```

or

```
hidden(-name=>'action', -value=>'default_value')

param('hidden_name', $new_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! That definitely clears up that initial confusion, but is there a way I can set the action based on the submit button? I need to change the mode and action based on one of two buttons being clicked.

Comment: @Gnippots, Actually, 20 minutes is pretty slow for us :) You can set the button's value, but IIRC, that changes the button's text too.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I can have the name of the button as action which will successfully change action param, but as you said, changes the name. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a try , not sure if it would work.

Try setting hidden variable before button and changing it before every button, so the new value should be taken.

For ex:

```
<input type='hidden' name='op' value='save'/>
<input type='submit' name='Save Form' value='SaveForm'/>
<input type='hidden' name='op' value='submit'/>
<input type='submit' name='Submit Form' value='SubmitForm'/>
<input type='hidden' name='op' value='cancel'/>
<input type='submit' name='Cancel Form' value='CancelForm'/>
```

You can check for hidden variable 'op' in perl script.